# How to connect Android app to mySQL *SPECIFICALLY*

Tags: php, android, mysql

After at least 10 hours of pouring over online resources, videos, and tutorials, I have two questions about connecting my android app with my mySQL database.

### Saving files

1) All the tutorials save the php files in C/WAMP/www/hello_php - for example, and so when you go to localhost/hello_php everything works.

--Where do I store my php files if I **don't** want to use localhost? i.e I want to use my mySQL's IP address.
--For example, the guy from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=38HDyEUEpCw) uses this:

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.168.0.3/~tahseen@amin/php/getAllCustomers.php");
```

--I presume the 192.168... is the IP of his server. Where did he save the "getAllCustomers.php" file?
--Note, I am using phpMyAdmin to handle the database.

### Existing JDBC code

2) I have already created all the code required to insert/update/delete elements from my DB. I have done this in Java using JDBC in eclipse. My understanding is that connecting my android app to my DB with JDBC is not ideal / unsafe / not recommended.

--Is all the code I wrote useless? i.e do I have to convert it all to php code?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: It's sort of beside the point, but judging by the URL you pasted from the video guy his entire home directory would be shared through his webserver...so don't do what he does. Better to use your webserver's root folder or configure an Apache alias to point to another path that's specifically for web files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The php file in your example is stored in the home folder of user 'tahseen@amin' in the subdirectory 'php'. You can put your php file anywhere on the server as long as it is accessible for HTTP requests. Usually you would put the files in a subdirectory of the root webfolder, which is usually in /var/www/ on the server.

As far as I know Android has no support for MySQL databases, so you have to do the queries via PHP (or another programming language, as long as it is accessible as a service on your server). You can then send HTTP requests from your Android application in order to perform the database modification via the PHP scripts on the server.